# Seeking dataset locating points of interest such as fire stations in Canada?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, point-of-interest, canada

Is there a dataset locating points of interest such as fire stations in Canada?

I tried using the one at http://www.mapcruzin.com/ but the accuracy was not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the data from openstreetmap. The data is free and can be obtained from overpass api.

Here is a [link to overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/yvR)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can download them from [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada.html) for a whole nation or provinces.